# Position of view changes in on drag listner

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, position, touch

I am placing views on parent layout. I want to drag the entire view on long click of L1. When I do long click on L1, the view enters in dragging mode but changes the position of touch to the center of the view (x,y).
I want to drag the view with holding the upper bar of layout(L1).

```
View:
    ______________
   |______L1______|
   |              |
y  |      L2      |
   |              |
   |______________|
           x


    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (event.getAction()) {

        //signal for the start of a drag and drop operation.
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // do nothing

            break;

        //the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            v.setBackground(targetShape);   //change the shape of the view
            break;

        //the user has moved the drag shadow outside the bounding box of the View
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            v.setBackground(normalShape);   //change the shape of the view back to normal
            break;

        //drag shadow has been released,the drag point is within the bounding box of the View
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
             doStuff();
              break;

        //the drag and drop operation has concluded.
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            v.setBackground(normalShape);   //go back to normal shape

        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the draging point in your image using `View.DragShadowBuilder` :

```
view.onProvideShadowMetrics(/* size of shadow */,
/* provide Point object with x cordinate equal to whole
 width of L1 and y cordinate equal to height of L1*/);
```

This way you can set your shadow touch point to L1

You can refer to [Developer page for DragShadowBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder.html#onProvideShadowMetrics%28android.graphics.Point,%20android.graphics.Point%29)

Comment: I tried this solution: found following sources
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/04/introduce-drag-and-drop-for-android-30.html
and this example
http://www.basedb.net/Index/detail/id/531.html

But not working :(

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: When I do long touch at corner of L1, suddenly touch position becomes center of the view... I want to drag view with holding the corner